# Partial View Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models:

- customer
- book_manager
- book

The `customer` can edit its own setting, like a profile account. However, it renders different models, such has `book`. To do this I decided to render the file `book/form` has follow `<% render book/form %>`.

When the profile page loads up, the customer may view in the book sections either nothing if nothing has been written before, or something if he already wrote something before. In the customer controller page I have the following code to fetch the information:

```
def edit
  @book = current_customer.books.order("created_at DESC").limit(1)
end
```

In the `books/_form.html.erb` I have then the following:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
  <% if @book.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @book.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In `book` controller `edit`, I have nothing or where should I place my command `@book` so they can speak?

I have the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Customers#edit

Showing /home/jean/rail/map/app/views/books/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @book.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least one simple error in your code

```
@book = current_user.books.order("created_at DESC").limit(1)
```

This will indeed return the most recent book, but it will return it in an array.

Instead of calling `limit(1)` you should use the method `first`

```
@book = current_user.books.order("created_at DESC").first
```

Comment: Thanks, i have one problem what would be the best if its empty? cause my new error is undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: The normal approach is in the `new` action do `@book = current_user.books.build` in the `edit` action do `@book = current_user.books.find(params[:id])`. In both these cases saying `form_for @book` works fine. Maybe you should try something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% render book/form.html.erb %>
```

should be

```
<%= render '/books/form' %>
```

Comment: Oops yeah thanks, that me writing it down on the forum, my bad edited